# How to read the connection string from a file in fitnesse?

Tags: sql, file, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim, dbfit

I want to test different queries, in fitnesse using dbfit, on a table present in different environment. Each environment has a different connection string. So instead of creating multiple pages for each environment(which is again a tedious task since each time a single change in the query may lead to change in all the test pages), I would like to store the connection string in a single file(may be text or excel sheet) and read the connection string out of it according to the requirement.

Can anyone help me out on how to proceed?

Comment: Hi Akshya, Welcome to Stack Overflow! :) When you're posting questions it would be really helpful to post what you already have. That way it becomes easier for the person helping to see what you already have.

Comment: Have you considered using a variable via `!define` (http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FitNesseWiki.MarkupLanguageReference.MarkupVariables) to store your connection string? You can then have a single suite that defines what to test, and reference that via 'symbolic links' (http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FitNesseWiki.SymbolicLinks) to have a suite per environment. So then you get the best of both worlds: single definition of what queries and ability to execute against different environments by selecting which suite to run.

Comment: Dbfit allows you to hold your connection strings in a file - see "Connect Using File" in http://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/docs/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the following is perfect fit for your requirements but I have an own "configuration" page for each database. Then I simply `include` the configuration page in the each of the test pages:

```
!include -c .DbFitSetup.UseDbX
```

You can switch the database during the test simply by including new configuration as the example below demonstrates:

```
user272735@dev:~/test/FitNesseRoot$ cat DbFitSetup/UseDbX/content.txt 
!path lib/*.jar
!|dbfit.OracleTest|
!|Connect|dbx.example.com:1531|<username>|<password>|dbx|
user272735@dev:~/test/FitNesseRoot$ cat DbFitSetup/UseDbY/content.txt 
!path lib/*.jar
!|dbfit.OracleTest|
!|Connect|dby.example.com:1531|<username>|<password>|dby|
user272735@dev:~/test/FitNesseRoot$ cat ExampleTestSuite/ExampleTest/content.txt 
!include -c .DbFitSetup.UseDbX

!|inspect query|select sysdate, global_name as db_name from global_name|

!include -c .DbFitSetup.UseDbY

!|inspect query|select sysdate, global_name as db_name from global_name|
user272735@dev:~/test/FitNesseRoot$
```